# get id of anchor inside list item, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, How to get id of list item, onclick of anchor tag inside list item. Ex.

```
<ul id="ul1">
    `<li id=li1"><a href="page1.html" onClick="get_id_of_parent(....);">Click</a></li>`
</ul>
```

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   var $this = $(this), id = $this.attr('id');

   // do something with id
});
```

This works because you the `this` variable refers to whatever li was clicked on

Answer (score 0):

If you want the id of the parent:

```
$('a').on('click',function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    // some script
});
```

**EDIT**
Take into considerations NewbornCodeMonkey's comment about the href linking to a different page...

Plain Javascript

You will need to add an onclick event to your anchor. You can't do it unobtrusively. So:

```
<a onclick="myfunction()" href="...">...</a>
```

javascript:

```
function myfunction() {
    var id = this.parentNode.id;
    // some script
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that you will be redirecting your page from the anchor tag. You can use the `href` attribute to instead call a javascript function, or remove the anchor tag and use jquery to react to a mouse event using either [the click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [the on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with click as a parameter.

Using the anchor tag, you can do something like this:

```
<li id=li1"><a href="myClickFunction();">Click</a></li>


function myClickFunction(){
  var id = this.parentNode.id;
  // use ID here
};
```

NOTE: If you still wish to redirect, then you can also leave the anchor tag pointing to `page1.html`, and use jquery to listen with one of the above functions that I have linked (.on or .click)

Another option instead of jquery is the [getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) function

an example of getAttribute:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("id");
```